# array list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array of size 155, my program consists of you inputting a word and then the word is searched for in the array.
However when i input `'176'` which is the last word in the array it gives a `list index out of range` error
Why is this?

```
i = resList.index(resiID) # --searchs list and give number where found, for last word gives 155
print len(resultss) # --prints 155
colour = resultss[i] # --error given on this line
```

Comment: I am betting that `i >= 155`. And what is the relationship between `resList` (where you get the index) and `resultss` (where you use the index?

Comment: Well you are wrong, printed it out and it was 155

Comment: What is `len(resList)`? And: Is resList of type `list`?

Comment: Are resList and resultss the same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is out of bounds. Here is how list indexes work:

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i = a.index(9)
>>> i
9
>>> a[i]
9
>>> a[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If the length of an index is `i`, then you can use any index in the range `0..i-1`. The last valid index is `len(mylist) - 1`.

155 is out of range, perhaps because you are getting an index in one list/iterable (`resList`) and using it as an index into a different/smaller list/iterable (`resultss`).

Answer (score 3):

That's expected behavior. If you have a `list` which has a `len` of `x`, then the `x` index is undefined.

Eg:

```
lst = [0,1]
print len(lst) # 2
print lst[0] # 0
print lst[1] # 1
print lst[len(lst)] #error
```

Comment: As an addendum: this is because Python lists are [zero-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).